# Is Redis too slow for Rails production I18n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, redis

I recently switch from the default Simple I18n backend to a Redis backend for my I18n. I did it so make it easier for us to handle the translations, but I've found that there was a substantial performance hit on every page.

I've run some Benchmarks with Rails 3.2 and Redis 2.6.4 installed on my MBP to demonstrate. I'm using [hiredis-rb](https://github.com/pietern/hiredis-rb) as my client.

It's a pretty clear difference when exercising the two different backends. With the simple backend there is a short delay on the first call - I assume the translations are being loaded into memory - and then great performance after that:

```
pry(main)> Benchmark.realtime { 500.times { I18n.t 'shared.slogan' } }
=> 0.143246
pry(main)> Benchmark.realtime { 500.times { I18n.t 'shared.slogan' } }
=> 0.00415
pry(main)> Benchmark.realtime { 500.times { I18n.t 'shared.slogan' } }
=> 0.004153
pry(main)> Benchmark.realtime { 500.times { I18n.t 'shared.slogan' } }
=> 0.004056
```

The Redis backend is consistently slow:

```
pry(main)> Benchmark.realtime { 500.times { I18n.t 'shared.slogan' } }
=> 0.122448
pry(main)> Benchmark.realtime { 500.times { I18n.t 'shared.slogan' } }
=> 0.263564
pry(main)> Benchmark.realtime { 500.times { I18n.t 'shared.slogan' } }
=> 0.232637
pry(main)> Benchmark.realtime { 500.times { I18n.t 'shared.slogan' } }
=> 0.122304
```

It makes absolute sense to me why this is slow for I18n... I'm queueing up dozens of I18n calls throughout my code base. If I could batch them together up front I'd be in good shape:

```
pry(main)> keys = $redis.keys[0..500]
pry(main)> Benchmark.realtime { $redis.mget keys }
=> 0.04264
```

But I don't really see a clean way to do this with any of the existing I18n backends. Has anybody out there tackled this problem?

## EDIT

I took Chris Heald's suggestion and created a backend with memoization a simple cache bust. The gist is up here:

https://gist.github.com/wheeyls/5650947

I'll try this out for a few days and then turn it into a gem.

## UPDATE

My solution is available as a gem now:

https://github.com/wheeyls/cached_key_value_store

And I also blogged about this problem:

http://about.g2crowd.com/faster-i18nredis-on-rails/

Comment: Where is your redis server in relation to the box running these benchmarks?

Comment: These were run are on my local machine. I'll edit my question to clarify.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Network traffic will always be slower than local work. You might consider an in-memory cache, and then just pull the current localization version on each request (or even just on a short timer) to determine whether to invalidate the cache. It looks like there's a Memoization module (per [the source here](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n/backend/key_value.rb)) that you can just mix into an I18n interface. Then, we just tweak the `#lookup` method so that every 5 minutes, it checks Redis for an updated locale version, and ensures that it increments the locale version when new translations are saved.

This gives you an in-memory cache of all your translations so it's a very fast lookup, while giving you the ability to make translation changes on-the-fly - your translations may take up to 5 minutes to update, but you don't have to do any explicit cache purging.

If you wanted, you could make it do the check on every request with a `before_filter` rather than just using the lazy 5-minute expiration, which means more requests to redis, but you wouldn't see any stale translations.

```
module I18n
  module Backend
    class CachedKeyValueStore < KeyValue
      include Memoize

      def store_translations(locale, data, options = {})
        @store.incr "locale_version:#{locale}"
        reset_memoizations!(locale)
        super
      end

      def lookup(locale, key, scope = nil, options = {})
        ensure_freshness(locale)
        flat_key  = I18n::Backend::Flatten.normalize_flat_keys(locale,
          key, scope, options[:separator]).to_sym
        flat_hash = memoized_lookup[locale.to_sym]
        flat_hash.key?(flat_key) ? flat_hash[flat_key] : (flat_hash[flat_key] = super)
      end

      def ensure_freshness(locale)
        @last_check ||= 0

        if @last_check < 5.minutes.ago
          @last_check = Time.now
          current_version = @store.get "locale_version:#{locale}"
          if @last_version != current_version
            reset_memoizations! locale
            @last_version = current_version
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I just hacked this up from reading the I18n source, and I haven't tested it at all, so it might need some work, but I think it communicates the idea well enough.

Comment: Nifty. This is basically the solution I had in mind, only better. I wonder why no one else seems to have dealt with this?

Comment: Nice. I'm going to yoink this and stick it in my to-use-later pile. :)